# AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition when using custom AMI to launch ElasticBeanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ec2

I have a custom AMI thats was created by following the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

When trying to launch a single instance environment using this custom AMI, I get this error:
"The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC, or a failed ECS instance"

However,

1. Using the same settings (including same VPC), but not specifying a custom AMI, the environment is created with no problem
2. The EC2 instance that was created is working fine, and is publicly available on the internet (I get the IIS default website at the public DNS, and can RDP into the instance)

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I got help from Amazon tech support to resolve this.

While step 14 in the link I posted with the question is "To avoid incurring additional AWS charges, terminate the EC2 instance.", what it does not mention that you need to terminate it using the "Shutdown with Sysprep" button (Image tab of the EC2Config UI).

After that, I created a new AMI which resolved the issue.